# Draw Line in Layout View with ArcObjects

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, line, layouts

I'm trying to draw a line on layout view on ArcMap with C# and ArcObjects. I'm working on this sample. But I have some problems.

1.) This code for  draw line on data view but I need to draw line on layout view(In box frame).I want to see properties of line element when I selected my line Item.

2.) When I click on this line in ArcMap, It become invisible..why is this happening?

This is Code Sample :

```c#
protected override void OnClick()

    {
        //drawing a polyline

        Point p1 = new PointClass();
        p1.X = 10; p1.Y = 10;

        IPoint p2 = new PointClass();
        p2.X = 20; p2.Y = 20;

        IPoint p3 = new PointClass();
        p3.X = 35; p3.Y = 15;

        IPoint p4 = new PointClass();
        p4.X = 40; p4.Y = 17;

        IPoint p5 = new PointClass();
        p5.X = 50; p5.Y = 19;

        IPoint p6 = new PointClass();
        p6.X = 60; p6.Y = 18;

        IPolyline polyline = new PolylineClass();
        IPointCollection pointColl = polyline as IPointCollection;
        pointColl.AddPoint(p1);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p2);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p3);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p4);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p5);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p6);

        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IActiveView activeView = mxdoc.ActiveView;
        IScreenDisplay screenDisp = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
        short screenCache = Convert.ToInt16(esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);
        screenDisp.StartDrawing(screenDisp.hDC, screenCache);

        IRgbColor color = new RgbColorClass();
        color.Red = 0; color.Blue = 0; color.Green = 0;

        ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
        simpleLineSymbol.Color = color;
        simpleLineSymbol.Width = 1;

        screenDisp.SetSymbol(simpleLineSymbol as ISymbol);
        screenDisp.DrawPolyline(polyline);

        screenDisp.FinishDrawing();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this code is failing is that you are writing to the screen cache, which you are obtaining from the `activeview` and this could be the `map` or  `pagelayout`; you need to be more explicit.

As soon as there is any sort of screen refresh you loose the graphic you have drawn.  If you want graphics to persist you need to be *storing* them in the PageLayout graphics container. The following VBA code shows you how to do this using your example points.

```vb
Public Sub drawline()

    ' Create a polyline
    Dim p1 As IPoint
    Set p1 = New Point
    p1.X = 10
    p1.Y = 10
    Dim p2 As IPoint
    Set p2 = New Point
    p2.X = 20
    p2.Y = 20
    Dim p3 As IPoint
    Set p3 = New Point
    p3.X = 30
    p3.Y = 15
    Dim p4 As IPoint
    Set p4 = New Point
    p4.X = 40
    p4.Y = 15
    Dim p5 As IPoint
    Set p5 = New Point
    p5.X = 50
    p5.Y = 19
    Dim p6 As IPoint
    Set p6 = New Point
    p6.X = 60
    p6.Y = 18
    Dim pPolyline As IPolyline
    Set pPolyline = New Polyline
    Dim pPointColl As IPointCollection
    Set pPointColl = pPolyline
    pPointColl.AddPoint p1
    pPointColl.AddPoint p2
    pPointColl.AddPoint p3
    pPointColl.AddPoint p4
    pPointColl.AddPoint p5
    pPointColl.AddPoint p6

    ' Create a colour
    Dim pColour As IRgbColor
    Set pColour = New RgbColor
    With pColour
        .Red = 0
        .Blue = 0
        .Green = 0
    End With

    ' Create a line symbol
    Dim pSimpleLineSymbol As ISimpleLineSymbol
    Set pSimpleLineSymbol = New SimpleLineSymbol
    With pSimpleLineSymbol
        .Width = 1
        .Style = esriSLSSolid
        .Color = pColour
    End With

    ' Create a line element, this is the graphic that will get added to the container
    Dim pElement As IElement
    Set pElement = New LineElement
    pElement.Geometry = pPolyline
    Dim pLineElement As ILineElement
    Set pLineElement = pElement
    pLineElement.Symbol = pSimpleLineSymbol

    ' Get the MXD
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument

    ' Get a handle on the page layout
    Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout
    Set pPageLayout = pMXD.PageLayout

    ' Get the graphics container of the PAGELAYOUT
    Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
    Set pGraphicsContainer = pPageLayout

    ' Add element and refresh
    pGraphicsContainer.AddElement pElement, 0
    Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
    Set pActiveView = pPageLayout
    pActiveView.Refresh
End Sub
```

*Note: the coordinates are interpreted as page coordinates, not geographic so the line that gets created is much larger than your page.*

Answer (score 0):

this is c# code for your solution :

```c#
protected override void OnClick() {

        //Create a polyline 

        Point p1 = new PointClass();
        p1.X = 10; p1.Y = 10;

        IPoint p2 = new PointClass();
        p2.X = 20; p2.Y = 20;

        IPoint p3 = new PointClass();
        p3.X = 35; p3.Y = 15;

        IPoint p4 = new PointClass();
        p4.X = 40; p4.Y = 17;

        IPoint p5 = new PointClass();
        p5.X = 50; p5.Y = 19;

        IPoint p6 = new PointClass();
        p6.X = 60; p6.Y = 18;


        IPolyline polyline = new PolylineClass();


        IPointCollection pointColl = polyline as IPointCollection;

        pointColl.AddPoint(p1);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p2);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p3);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p4);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p5);
        pointColl.AddPoint(p6);

        // Create a colour 

        IRgbColor color = new RgbColorClass();
        color.Red = 0; color.Blue = 0; color.Green = 0;

        // Create a line symbol

        ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
        simpleLineSymbol.Color = color;
        simpleLineSymbol.Width = 1;

        // Create a line element, this is the graphic that will get added to container

        IElement element = new LineElement();
        element.Geometry = polyline;

        ILineElement lineElement;
        lineElement = element as ILineElement;
        lineElement.Symbol = simpleLineSymbol;

        // Get the Mxd

        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;

        // Get the handle on the page layout

        IPageLayout pageLayout = new PageLayout();
        pageLayout = mxdoc.PageLayout;

        // Get the graphics container of the PageLayout

        IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = pageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;

        // Add element an refresh
        graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);
        IActiveView activeView = pageLayout as IActiveView;
        activeView.Refresh();
   }
```